# Filling one table using another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables as follows:

[image]

[image]

As you may note, the first table has a monthly frequency (date column), while the second table has a quarterly frequency. Here is what I would like to do:

- For each issueid from table 1, I would like to look at the date, determine what is the previous end of quarter, and go fetch data from table 2 corresponding to that issue for that end of quarter, and insert it in the first table in the last two columns.
- For example: take issueid 123456 and date 1/31/2014. The previous end of quarter is 12/31/2013. I would like to go to table 1, copy `q_exp` and `q_act` that correspond to that issueid and 12/31/2013, and paste it into the first table.

Of course, I would like to fill the entire first table and minimize manual inserts.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with syntax resembling, "insert into table2 (field1) select field2 from table1 where whatever"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
UPDATE issues
SET q_exp=(SELECT TOP 1 q.q_exp
           FROM quarterlyTable q
           WHERE q.issueid=i.issueid
           AND q.[date]<=i.[date]
           ORDER BY q.[date] DESC)
,q_act=   (SELECT TOP 1 q.q_act
           FROM quarterlyTable q
           WHERE q.issueid=i.issueid
           AND q.[date]<=i.[date]
           ORDER BY q.[date] DESC)
FROM issues i
```

Comment: I get the following errors: 
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "i.issueid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "i.date" could not be bound.